# How to download Maven reports after a GitLab CI job failure

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm quite newbie with GitLab CI.
How can I export the Maven surefire reports when my job fails.
I've tried with artifacts but it only works with job in success.

Is there a convenient approach for exporting reports ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found by myself. Use "when"

```
   job:
      artifacts:
        when: on_failure
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if surefire-reports are into subdirectories - ie. for  multi-modules maven projects.

Define a command to collect surefire-reports and put it at the root level in `./surefire-reports`

```
variables:
 COPY_REPORTS: 'find ./myjavaproject/ -type d -path "./*/surefire-reports" -exec cp -r {} . \;'
```

Then setup this command in an `after_script` section (cf. [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#before_script-and-after_script) ):

```
 after_script:
    - eval $COPY_REPORTS
```

You could `always` publish artifacts (on_failure/success) (cf. [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts-when) ):

```
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
    - surefire-reports/
```